# Why is node border not rendered when using long label in Graphviz with dot2tex?

Tags: dot2tex

I have this `.dot` code:

```
digraph {
    ABC -> DF
    ABC -> E
    E -> G
    H -> IJ
}
```

I use command `dot2tex --figonly` to convert it to tex file. For some unknown reason, It doesn't show ellipse around letters "ABC" (resulting .tex file is not containing ellipse where it should, there is no border). Setting it as `label` attribute does not work either. Anything longer than two letters is not working too. Anything shorter works. How can I fix this?